# TypeError: styleSheet.getName is not a function when importing components from npm based react libs using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, server-side-rendering

#### Context

I'm writing a react component library based on [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/) in NPM to be shared across my downstream React projects.

All of my projects are isomorphic React apps. They implement Styled components server-side rendering (SSR) as [outlined in the official documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#server-side-rendering) as such:

```
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(App));
const css = sheet.getStyleElement().map((el, idx) => (el ? React.cloneElement(el, { key: idx }) : el));
const page = <Html content={html} state={apolloState} assetMap={assetMap} css={css} helmet={helmet} />;
res.send(`<!doctype html>\n${ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(page)}`);
res.end();
```

#### Problem

When I import a component from  my aforementioned react component library from npm and call it in my project, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: styleSheet.getName is not a function
    at ComponentStyle.generateAndInjectStyles (/project/node_modules/my-react-component-library/node_modules/styled-components/lib/models/ComponentStyle.js:95:37)
    at StyledComponent.generateAndInjectStyles (/project/node_modules/my-react-component-library/node_modules/styled-components/lib/models/StyledComponent.js:154:40)
    at StyledComponent.componentWillMount (/project/node_modules/my-react-component-library/node_modules/styled-components/lib/models/StyledComponent.js:192:40)
    ...
```

#### Questions

1. Is this problem coming from my npm library not enabling SSR or the end-user implementation of the styled components ssr?
2. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by exporting the stylesheet via webpack's [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) in the upstream npm react library and calling it from my downstream app.